# blsAPI in R only current year is showing

Tags: r

Hello I am trying to use the Bureau of Labor Statistics API in R to pull in Occupational Employment and Wage Statistics on the Statistics profession.

I am working with these packages

```
library(blsAPI)
library(tidyverse)
```

I created this function to help put in IDseries together which is what the blsAPI needs. For more info on ID series check out https://www.bls.gov/help/hlpforma.htm#OE

```
OEWS_IDSeries<- function(Prefix = "OE", 
                         SeasonalAdjust = "U", 
                         AreaType = "N", 
                         Area = "0000000", 
                         Industry = "111000",
                         Occupation = "110000", 
                         DataType = "01"){
  paste(c(Prefix, SeasonalAdjust, AreaType, Area, Industry, Occupation, DataType), collapse = "") 
                        }
```

Using my function to request data from 2020 to 2018

```
test = OEWS_IDSeries(Area = "0000000", #National
                     Occupation = "152041", #Statistics Occupation
                     Industry = "000000", #Cross-industry, Private, Federal, State, and Local Government
                     DataType = "01") #Employment

payload = list(
  seriesid = test,
  startyear = 2018,
  endyear = 2020
)

single <- blsAPI(payload, return_data_frame = T, api_version = 1)
head(single)
```

This code results in this:

```
  year period periodName value                  seriesID

1 2020    A01     Annual 38860 OEUN000000000000015204101
```

My question is where is the data for the previous years?

I can download and visibly see the data present in these tables https://www.bls.gov/oes/tables.htm